# Javascript project with multiple files

Tags: javascript, ide

What is the best IDE/editor/anything-else that manage javascript project on multiple files? I mean, is there a way of developing projects on multiple files and then kinda "build" the project into a single minified file? I've seen that this is done in lots of projects on the net. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/), or simply concatenate your files using a simple build script.

Comment: Install node js and write your own build system , in javascript. if yo u can code in js , you should be able to code that in 5 mins max.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any all-in-one solution for that (yet). You need to combine several tools:

- IDE: WebStorm, Aptana, or even Notepad++
- Cross-Compiler: Sass, CoffeeScript etc.
- Compressor: Google Closure Compiler, UglifyJS or YUICompressor
- Build tool triggering a build process, managing folder structures etc.
  Personally, I use loads of Bash scripts, but I've seen people use Maven or Ant
- There are also Frameworks with integrated build tools, supporting dev/production mode, something like qooxdoo, Sencha, ...

If you're on a small to medium-sized project, running the tools manually might be the best solution in terms of cost-benefit ratio, since automation requires quite a bit of work.

Comment: Thanks, it's frustrating that such a diffuse language does not have any good project management system.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do that.
In my case we using nodejs and requirejs with uglify lib. [you can read it here](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html)

It gives me an ability to deploy minified files with one bash script.

Answer (score 0):

The best editor for multiple files project is WebStorm from JetBrains !!!
You can use online resources for merging the files. http://jscompress.com/ is a good tool for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this really easily in Visual Studio 2012 using [Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6)

---

Bundles can easily be edited and they output combined and combined minified files every time you save one of the bundled files.

[image]